# Create Special offer layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

How can I create a layout that contains the red view on top left corner

See the picture below to have a better idea of what I am seeking for

Thank you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBgN9.png)

Comment: You can simply save this promotion red text as an image, load it as a drawable and add it to your view.

Answer (score 1):

check out these libraries on Github

https://github.com/wavever/TagCornerImageView

https://github.com/czy1121/cornerlabelview

https://github.com/shts/TriangleLabelView